# Pulling the value of a cell based on a condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 4 columns, three of the columns have values in it and in the fourth column I want to put in the value of one of the first three columns based on if I select 1,2 or 3 in a completely different area.  For example Rows A1:A5 contain 1,2,3,4,5  and B1:B5 contain 6,7,8,9,10, and C1:C5 contains 11,12,13,14,15 so D1:D5 I wanted a formula that would pull the information from columns A, B or C based on the value of E1, so if E1 = 2, then all the D1:D5 will be the same as B1:B5

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

`cybernetic.nomad`'s answer shows a neat trick using `INDEX` in which one specifies just one parameter after the range and Excel is forced to consider the context and decide whether it is to be a row or column value.

But it IS a *"and populate down"* formula. Might need or want that. If you want a dynamic "spill" formula, use something like the following:

```
=INDEX(A1:C5,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:C5)),E1:E5)
```

Editing for real ranges of course.

*Caveat:  It returns 0's for any empty cells, so if you have such, or use an over-enthusiastic range, you will need to keep that in mind and provide accordingly.*

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 =INDEX(A1:C1,E$1)
```

and populate down